# Visual Studio Load test CPU Usage

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, load-testing, performance-testing

I'm running visual studio 2013 ultimate load test in my local system which has i7-3840QM processor, SSD with 2.8GHz processor.

My load scenario is ramping up 50 users for every 30 seconds upto 500 users. When I checked my CPU usage, it shows 100% and looks like its using all 4 cores. (Please see the attached screenshot)[image]

Here are my questions: 
1. Is it OK to continue the test when CPU usage shows 100%? 
2. Do we have anything like "Load Test Virtual User Pack 2010" for VS 2013 version? 
3. What are other options available ? (I'm planning for Test Rigs, if the single system doesn't work)

Appreciate any help.

Comment: (1) No. (2) No, unlimited as described in the documentation. (3) Use two or more agents.

Comment: when you will run VS app server load testing every thing on same machine it will for sure shoot 100 % :P

Answer (score 1):

Could you do some profiling?  First profile CPU and find which processes are hogging the CPU, For the CPU hogging process, find the function(s) that cost most of the CPU cycles.  Intel VTune is a great commercial profile. For open source one, you can try valgrind.

Good luck.